# Spring Security 5 generates different encoded string than Spring Security 4 using SHA-1 encoding

Tags: java, spring-security, sha1

Our dev team has been notified that our application will no longer be deployed until we upgrade from Spring Security 4.x to Spring Security 5, due to an authorization bypass vulnerability in earlier versions of Spring Security.  I'm struggling with our authentication code, which uses the Spring Security 4 SHAPasswordEncoder, which has been removed from Spring Security 5.  I have a simple application that encodes a text string as an SHA-1 encoded string, and I have "successfully" migrated the code for that app to Spring Security 5, but I'm getting a very different string back when encoding it.

The old application:

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder;

/**
 * Small java utility to take a single string and generate an SHA encoded string from
 * the original string, for use as an EIS local password
 * 
 * Usage:
 *      PwGen <string_to_encode>
 *
 */
public class PwGen {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PwGen pwGen = new PwGen();
        pwGen.generatePassword(args);
    }
    
    private void generatePassword(final String[] args) {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            usage();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Generating password");
        
        ShaPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new ShaPasswordEncoder();
        
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encodePassword((String)args[0], "");
        System.out.println(encodedPassword);
    }
    
    private void usage() {
        System.out.println("Usage: pwGen <string_to_encode>");
        System.out.println("Application will return an encoded string for use as a password");
    }
}
```

The new application:

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

/**
 * Small java utility to take a single string and generate an SHA encoded string from
 * the original string, for use as an EIS local password
 * 
 * Usage:
 *      PwGen <string_to_encode>
 *
 */
public class PwGen {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PwGen pwGen = new PwGen();
        pwGen.generatePassword(args);
    }
    
    private void generatePassword(final String[] args) {

        if (args.length != 1) {
            usage();
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Generating password");
        
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("SHA-1");
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(args[0]);
        
        System.out.println(encodedPassword);
    }
    
    private void usage() {
        System.out.println("Usage: pwGen <string_to_encode>");
        System.out.println("Application will return an encoded string for use as a password");
    }
}
```

Using the old application, encoding the string "password" produced the following encoded string: 5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8

This was an easily predictable solution, as our database contains the exact same string.

The new application produces a different string every time I run it, so I no longer can generate specific passwords for users.  I am very aware that this entire process is not secure, but the application is old and there will be a complete rewrite in the not-to-distant future, so management is not excited about funding an intermediate rewrite.  How do I guarantee that the MessageDigestPasswordEncoder brings back the same string as the actual encoded password?

Comment: You can use the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` implementation and migrate your password smoothly by adding a prefix to them, you can opt for a more secure algorithm going forward and still support matching the old ones